# R equivalent to Scikit-Learn make_regression() function

Tags: r, scikit-learn

I would like to create some sample data for use in regression models in R.

I have found the `make_regression()` function in Scikit-Learn which allows for output of numeric sample data with some useful parameters such as column and row count as well as number of useful features and amount of noise, but I would like to find an equivalent in R if it exists.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know any. However, you could use Reticulate package to create the dataset in Python and use it in R. Would this help?